# Identifying non used functions through unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have written a helper class which has many public functions in it.

Few of the functions I have called through different files in the same project.

Few function I am not calling as I thinking I use it for future.

Few function I may be written mistakenly and may not be useful in future or it may be a total waste.

Question:

Is it possible to write test cases to check which functions are called and which are NOT called?

Can we write test cases to make the test fail if the helper function is not used?

Is it a best practice to keep the unused functions in help class?

Update :

> If I keep unused functions in my class for future reference and write
>   unit tests for that, test coverage includes those functions and gives
>   wrong test coverage, so is it right to write test cases for those
>   functions or is it better to remove those unused functions?

Comment: About best practice, remember [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). Also read up on the basics of [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). Furthermore, you can check which functions are called during tests using [mock objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object).

Comment: Normally you would/could do this with a testcoverage tool.

Comment: @rene Wouldn't a testcoverage tool only find out which functions are **tested**?

Comment: Visual studio has those little information lines above methods. They go like "0 reference| 0 changes| 0 authors, 0 changes" - "0 references" is a fairly good hint they are not being called as a starter.

Comment: @Fildor it will do both. It will show which lines/methods/classes are tested and which not. Look at ncover: https://www.ncover.com/ or what is available in the VS2015 SKU: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx or [EMMA](http://emma.sourceforge.net/) that has via Jenkins plugins options to cover for c#

Comment: @rene Still unclear to me. I read the question in the sense of OP is trying to find out if some functions are actually used _at runtime_. He is trying to use the Test-System for that. So, it's not really about Test-Coverage.

Comment: @Fildor sure, I understand the question in the same way you do, which is why I left a comment instead of an answer as you're correct that a coverage tool is not what the OP is asking for but I felt it might be worth mentioning such tools in case the OP didn't realize these tools existed

Comment: @rene OK, now it makes all sense.

Comment: Hi, all could you please comment on the updated part of my questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, probably not as it would rely on you having 100% coverage of the rest of your system and using some kind of code coverage tool. Something like [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) code inspection will tell you which of the methods it doesn't think are being used.

Comment: Hi all could you please comment on the updated part of my questions?

Comment: Most of the time its best to remove unused functions,  see the YAGNI principle for that @SmartestVEGA